# MySQL string used in ORDER BY FIELD

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have an array of values stored in a single cell as a comma-separated string, thus:

```
"0,9,10,2,7,3,4,5,6,8,1,11,12"
```

I also have a table (table1) with a column (order) with these numbers in a different sequential order:

```
id|order
0 |5
1 |3
2 |4
3 |1
4 |2
etc
```

**What I want to do is `SELECT` the "order" string from one table (table2) and use those values in an `ORDER BY FIELD` command when SELECTing from table1.**

This should return row in this order: `3,4,1,2,0`.

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT id
FROM table1
WHERE table1_id = 3746 
ORDER BY FIELD(orderKey, (
  SELECT `order` FROM table2 
  WHERE table2_id = 3746) 
);
```

The problem seems to be that the `SELECT`order`FROM table2` is returned as a string which `ORDER BY FIELD` doesn't want to accept as input. It does `SELECT` the rows, but they are not in the specified order.

I have tried type-casting, but I may not have done this correctly. I also have sought an equivalent to a php `explode` function, to no avail.

MySQL version is 5.6.41

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
select *
from table1
order by find_in_set(`order`, (select `order` from table2 where table2_id = 3746))
```

This will work if all the values in the column `order` of `table1` exist in the string returned by the subquery as you mention in the question:

> I also have a table (table1) with a column (order) with **these
>   numbers** in a different sequential order

.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9kZMQ8Jsjiw2ZSMm8ENwQi/0).
Results:

```
| id  | order |
| --- | ----- |
| 4   | 2     |
| 1   | 3     |
| 2   | 4     |
| 0   | 5     |
| 3   | 1     |
```

Comment: I am struggling to make this work. I keep getting ```Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'order' in 'order clause'```. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm using the column names from your question. If the name is not `order` change it to the actual name. Also since `order` is a reserved word surround it with backticks (ascii code 96).

Comment: Got it! My error was a simple syntax problem — a.k.a. _flatulus cranius._ Thanks very much for your help. You have taught me something new today. Cheers.